# Objective C, A Question about reference counting

Tags: objective-c

```
 -(void)addNode{
       Node *node = [[Node alloc] init];
       [node fromBytes:nodeData];
       [neighborNodes addObject:[node retain]];
       [node release];
 }
```

Let's say I have a method like that. A node is being allocated and added to the NSMutableArray (neighborNodes is NSMutableArray..) I am not sure [node retain] statement is needed here. Can I just do this? I took retain word out and didn't release node.. Which one is correct? Thanks in advance...

```
 -(void)addNode{
       Node *node = [[Node alloc] init];
       [node fromBytes:nodeData];
       [neighborNodes addObject:node];
 }
```

Comment: I’ve noticed you haven’t accepted any answers to your questions. Quoting Stack Overflow’s FAQ, ‘When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (If you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)’

Comment: Don't forget to show this question's best answer some love too! If you're not satisfied with it even though it has four upvotes, then leave a comment on it detailing why :) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No its not needed

addObject does a retain on the object

IOW

```
-(void)addNode{
       Node *node = [[Node alloc] init];
       [node fromBytes:nodeData];
       [neighborNodes addObject:node];
       [node release];
 }
```

would be correct.